# Issue while generating number to show sequence in ssrs report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am facing issue with SSRS report where I trying to generate numbers for showing sequence of filds. I am generating this data by using code in report. but it having two major issues.

1. Here I am able get numbers in my parent report but in sub report this numbering is not getting start from 1 it continues inside subreport and not considering parent report values. 
   My code is as given below. which will generate numbers like

1 dummy data
 1.1 dummy data
 1.2 dummy data
2 dummy data
 2.1 dummy data

```
Dim currentValue As Double
Public Function GetCounter(ByVal iCounter As Double, ByVal incrementCounter 
  As Boolean) As Double
    If (incrementCounter = true) Then
        iCounter = (iCounter + currentValue)
        currentValue = (currentValue + 0.1)
    End If

    Return iCounter
End Function
```

but with my sub report I want to generate numbers like

1 dummy data
 1.1 dummy data
  1.1.1 dummy data
   1.1.1.1 dummy data
   1.1.1.2 dummy data
  1.1.2 dummy data
  1.1.2.1 dummy data
  1.1.2.2 dummy data
1.2 and so on.

I am not able get how can achive this with subReport.

Second issue is.

2. some fildes were I am getting correct numbers like from parrent report, having problem in PDF some extrea numbers are appearing in report and also numbers displaying in report and in PDF are diferent for some filds.

[image]

I am not able to get why this issue is comming and what solution I have to apply.

Pleas if any one knows solution to these issue please help me..

Comment: I think it would help to see the design of your table structure. It could be an issue with the group nesting.

Comment: Above data is in single row, in database there is no sperate tables for these filds. In table we store data of second level filds and heading i.e first level text is hard codedd in report.

Comment: I meant the table design in your report, not the database. As far as the report design is concerned, it doesn't matter where the dataset comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following custom code

```
Dim numbers = New Integer() {0, 0, 0, 0} 

Public Function Seq(lev as Integer) As String

Select Case lev
Case 0
numbers(0) = numbers(0)+1
numbers(1) = 0
numbers(2) = 0
numbers(3) = 0
Return Cstr(numbers(0))

Case 1
numbers(1) = numbers(1)+1
numbers(2) = 0
numbers(3) = 0
Return Cstr(numbers(0)) & "." & Cstr(numbers(1))

Case 2
numbers(2) = numbers(2)+1
numbers(3) = 0
Return Cstr(numbers(0)) & "." & Cstr(numbers(1)) & "." & Cstr(numbers(2))

Case 3
numbers(3) = numbers(3)+1
Return Cstr(numbers(0)) & "." & Cstr(numbers(1)) & "." & Cstr(numbers(2)) &"." & Cstr(numbers(3))

End Select

End Function
```

The expression for group1 will be = Code.Seq(0), for group2 will be =Code.Seq(1), ... etc